# Mailing List For Students

Tags: email

So I need a mailing list software for 450+ students who can subscribe to the list, get a mail send by me to all of them, read previous mail digest etc.

An added feature would be an online repository/archive where they can browse previous mails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/).

That seems to fit your requirements.

Pricing depends upon the level of usage that you expect.  For 450 students, you should come into the free category.